# How do I enable file colors in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

**"IntelliJ IDEA"** has a feature that allows the user to customize the colors that project files, system files & library files are highlighted as. It even allows conditional coloring according to custom "scopes". Is there a way to do that in VS Code?

Comment: No, VS Code doesn't support that feature. That is something you will typically find in an **IDE**, ***'Visual Studio Code'*** is an editor. Editors & IDEs are conceptually different. An IDE uses the word "Integrate", because it often integrates with the environment you are working in, in-which you will often gain access to an SDK (such as Java's JDK _aka_ Java Development Kit), this always an integration with the JRE (Java Runtime Environment, ETC). "Visual Studio 2022", its the same thing, the IDE, intigrates with windows, giving you access to the windows SDK, which can be used by

Comment: most C languages. I think the 'F#' & **'D'** languages can also use the windows SDK, anyway... VS Code doesn't integrate with a system, so usually people don't have a bunch of system files loaded into the editor, ***however;*** the lines are getting blurred, and I understand that this is changing. The definition of an Editor, and an IDE, are becoming very similar, but there are still clear differences. In otherwords, we may start seeing features like that released in the future (I think there will be), but we are not at that point yet.

Comment: Really if you want a an interface that offers a clear definitive view of your program, and the system that it is integrated in, an IDE is the right tool to use. ECLIPSE is a very popular free IDE. Visual Studio 2022 is free if your on windows. There is a paid version as well, but I find that you don't need it unless your developing a massive project.

Comment: Yeah, the lines are blurred. VS Code has a debugger, a plugin allowing to debug inside a Docker container, and lots of other goodies. I'd say that makes it an IDE. What's the use case for each? I am using Go.

Comment: I am on Mac. I could probably get a license, but my understanding is that they are different enough to make the back and forth transition cumbersome? Visual Studio isn't a superset of VS Code? 

I've been an early adopter of Eclipse, but I think IntelliJ has pretty much superseded it now. But now my team is deploying in dev containers, so I have to cross to the dark side :-)

Comment: Go, has great support in VS Code, though I have never written Go, I know that the "Go Community" really likes VS Code. Microsoft seems to really support GO as well. Microsoft has also extended its hand to Apple in many cases. One such case is for the first time, they have made available, Visual Studio 2022 on a mac https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/

Comment: I agree, I like intelliJ. 2BH, I get access for free, because I am a Computer Science student. But its not the only thing I get for free, I also get free Azure stuff (I'm 37 though lol, so kind of an old student, but it has allowed me to experience everything out their) I can say for certain, JetBrains is doing great stuff. If I write Java, I will only do it using IntelliJ.

Comment: What's the history behind these 2 products, why is Microsoft maintaining both?

Comment: Microsoft has a new CEO, a guy who is American, but was born in India. He has changed the complete direction of the company. Bill Gates pretty much stepped away from the company all together in 2014, but was getting less & less involved before that. Once Bill Gates left to enjoy his fortune (which I don't blame him for doing), the company suffered. I forget how many CEO's it had, but there just seemed to be a lack of a good buisness model. This new guy came in and hey, we are fighting against "opensource" but opensource is the future. Like it or not, we need to get on board.

Comment: It completely changed Microsoft.

Comment: this is the guy here, [Satya Nadella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satya_Nadella)

Comment: He actually has a great story.

Comment: So, what's the plan, maintain two divergent products forever?

Comment: Well fundamentally they are different, and Visual Studio 2022 gives access to the Windows SDK. VS Code is an MIT Licensed opensource contribution by Microsoft,  that the community maintains. Microsoft, won't (and it is understandable why) license there SDK under a opensource (or freeware GNU-style) license. That would be like giving a way billions, and probably wouldn't be helpful to Windows anyway. Charging for some software ensures that the software is maintained, and allows for the funding of open source projects like VS Code.

Comment: I mean, I can't say what they will do in the future, but I do think there will come a point where VS Code is more capable for writing languages like C++, and most definatly C#. Infact, VS Code is technically an IDE by definition for TypeScript. TypeScript actually works sort of like an SDK, and when you configure its version in vscode the sretting actually references the TSC executable's directory as being the directory to an SDK. TypeScript is also a statically typed language, that uses a compiler. Honestly, typescript feels a bit like Java or C# (not like C++ though).

Comment: So, it feels like Microsoft is headed in the direction of developing, an IDE/EDitor for opensource, and a pure IDE for Proprietary (which one could argue thats what we already have). I think its more of a legal issue, with licensing than it is a support issue.

Comment: `"typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"` <-- example of VS Code referencing tsc as sdk. TSDK = TypeScript Standard Development Kit, like the JDK is a Java Development Kit, and the windows SDK is Windows Standard Development Kit. Typically we only see semantics like this in an IDE. It could not mean anything, but I think it shows that those who are engineering the software, are looking at it from the perspective of typescript, which is Microsoft Developed, and is what VS Code is written in, as an IDE style language.

Comment: Because VS Code is written in TypeScript, TypeScript is integrated with it, not in the traditional context that Indegrated is used with IDE, but nevertheless; it is integration, and it feels like integration. VS Code is by far at its best when used to write TypeScript, JavaScript, using the Electron & React frameworks, and when the software runs in the Node RTE, or in the Chrome Browser (which offers JS debug-tooling that is very powerful, unlike any ECMAS debugger before it)

Comment: Its a fun topic, but this is only my speculation, I would be a mad-man if I said that any of what I am saying is 100% cannon. But I think it does help to draw a picture of where we are at, and where things could be going.